How to replace NEST class Attachment using Elastic.Client.Elasticsearch?
Previously, I used the NEST library to use Elasticsearch. This is now deprecated. I have implemented the recommended Elastic.Client.Elasticsearch. However, this library does not recognise the Attachment or ElasticClient class.
How do I deal with this problem?
using System;
//using Nest;
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch;

namespace Contracts
{
    public class ElasticDocument
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public int Date { get; set; }

        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        // class Attachment is unknown in Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch
        public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
    }
}

Client...
private ElasticClient? ElasticClient { get; set; }

private bool Initialisation()
{
    ElasticClient = ClientFactory.GetElasticClient(MyElasticConfigurations);


Helpful is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html
